# trying to use .load() to pull in multiple link from a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to jquery and I'm trying to learn new things with coding. I have a slider working on 5 topics that slide left to right. For each of the 5 items in that slider there is a link to a different web page internally,that i want to bring in content using the .load() method into a blank div.

Other than the pictures not working and the slider part not scrolling, here is what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be grateful, in pointing me into the right direction. [Code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/6cuam/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#te").click(function(evt) {
        $('#news').empty().load('ppv_ons.html #ppv');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }); // end click

});  // end ready   
</script>
```

Comment: Code formatting helps with these issues

Comment: Sorry, I was fighting with website to post the code.

Comment: Did you check FireBug (or similar) to see if you are getting response text? Did you check the path to the included file? Did you make sure the is an `id="ppv"` in the included file?

Covering the basic questions.

Comment: There is an id="ppv" on the ppv_ons.html. I did check the path and thats correct. Im not getting back any error messages in console. I think that I dont have the right code where it searches for herf links and then send those link to the empty <div> tag when clicked.

Comment: Where in your posted jsfiddle is there an element with id "te"?

Comment: Click on the text "Code is here" for link to jsfiddle.

Comment: That's what I was referring to. I did find the "te" element though, and clicked on it. I found that it was requesting ppv_ons.html, but of course that's a relative URL, and on jsfiddle it just gets you a 404 page.

Comment: Try moving the `id="te"` to the `<a>` and not the `<div>`. I changed a bit of the code and the click is working fine. I also moved the `evt.preventDefault();` to the beginning of the function. http://jsfiddle.net/6cuam/8/

Comment: I did what you suggested Biotox. When I click on the link it opens the ppv_ons.html in another window. I am also getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input now

Comment: Do you have a place to see the file loading actually working? I created the same page setup on my local (from your JsFiddle) and a test include file in the same directory. The load is working on my local.

Comment: I do have a place where I can upload it to the school server. Got it to work, but want to say thanks all for the help.

Comment: Not a problem! Have fun with jQuery `:)` FireBug is your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made HTML this:

```
<div class="link" id="te"><a href="ppv_wm.html" target="blank">Find out more</a></div>
```

Into

```
<div class="link"><a id="te" href="ppv_wm.html" target="blank">Find out more</a></div>
```

And updated the jQuery to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#te").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#news').empty().load('ppv_ons.html #ppv');
  });
}); // end ready
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6cuam/8/

Answer (score 0):

you can get your content like

**$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#te").click(function(evt) { 

          $('#news').empty();

           $('#news').load($('#ppv').html());

           evt.preventDefault();

     }); 

});**

Comment: This is absolutely not what they're trying to do.

Comment: I got it to work, but what I had to do was edit modify your code to read $('#news').load('ppv_ons.html #ppv').html(); instead. But I want to say thank you to all who helped me!